# configure automatic email php code to task scheduler

Tags: php, mysql, cron, scheduled-tasks

Please guide me how can I configure my PHP code that sends automatic emails on monthly bases to task scheduler in windows.

Answer (score -1):

You can use PHP's "mail" function or the popular class PHPMailer. But I strongly advise (as long as it is NOT spam) to use postmarkapp.com. It handles all the hard work of creating a solid e-mail service (SPF, DKIM, etc.). You will need very basic knowledge of APIs for this to work though, but it is very easy compared to what they provide.

If you are running this from your own server you find the "Scheduled Tasks" in the start menu. But I would strongly advise that you create a cron job (if you are on a shared host this is typically done in your controlpanel)

Comment: thats my question how can I create cron job in windows platform then configure my php file to that cron job. please guide me